# Is this assignment thread-safe?

Tags: c#, thread-safety

Is the `_dict` assignment in `Load()` threadsafe? Meaning that reading from the dictionary in the `Get` metod will not occur during `_dict` change in `Load()`. I know pointer assignment is atomic so I put the lock just so the complier will not reorder the code.

```
public class A
{
    private readonly object _lock = new object();

    private Dictionary<int, int> _dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    public Task Load()
    {
        Dictionary<int, int> temp;
        lock (_lock)
        {
            var list = GetFromDb(); //Some db query that returns an updated data
            temp = list.toDictionary(<some conversion>);
        }

        _dict = temp;
    }

    public int Get(int key)
    {
        return _dict[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to use a dictionary across threads then use a `ConcurrentDictionary` and then there can be no need to worry.

Comment: Hi thanks, but not what I was asking...

Comment: Why assign a new `Dictionary` to `_dict` where you declare it and then throw that away and replace it when you call `Load`?

Comment: @user2169241 you should [edit] the question to clarify what you are asking. "Thread safe" by itself does not mean much - I'm pretty sure code with/without lock would behave the same as write can't happen before GetFromDb returns... and Get is not synchronized with Load - so results are unpredictable in either case...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to protect against here?

Comment: What exactly are your requirements for your code to be thread-safe?  Do you want to prevent that the dictionary might be loaded form the database more than once? Then your code is not thread-safe. Do you want to be sure that when you leave the `Load()` method, that `_dict` has a new value? This should be the case (if I don't oversee anything, which is quite easy in the topic thread-safety).

Comment: No it isn't thread safe because you lock retrieval (`GetFromDb()` but not `_dict= temp;`

Comment: As a side note, the `Load` method doesn't compile. It has a `Task` return type, but there is no `return` inside the method.

Answer (score 2):

No, this code is not thread-safe in a way that reading via the `Get()` method cannot happen while the dictionary changes in the `Load` method. You also need a lock in your `Get` method to achieve this:

```
public class A
{
    private readonly object _lock = new object();

    private Dictionary<int, int> _dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    public async Task Load()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            var list = await GetFromDb(); //Some db query that returns an updated data
            _dict = list.toDictionary(<some conversion>);
        }
    }

    public int Get(int key)
    {
        lock(_lock)
        {
            return _dict[key];
        }
    }
}
```

With that code, if thread 1 calls `Load` and thread 2 calls `Get` while thread 1 still executes `Load`, thread 2 will wait until thread 1 is finished with the execution of `Load`.

Answer (score 1):

No, if a field is changed from multiple threads it should be marked as [volatile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile). Otherwise there could be situations where the `Get`-method is inlined in a loop, and the reference will not be updated, since the compiler optimizes as if the program was single threaded in the absence of synchronization. The chance of this is probably small, but it is easy enough to mark the field as volatile.

With regard to doing loading the dictionary, doing some processing on it, and then assigning it to a shared field, that should be safe. Assignment is atomic, and so is looking up a reference. So the `Get`-method will either get the old dictionary or the new one. But since the dictionary that is referenced by the `_dict`-field never changes, the example should be thread safe.